# Audio file uploading in vuetify laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

Just started using vuetify.js and vue.js with laravel, and I'm trying to create a form where the user can submit a audio file of whatever type (.mp3, etc) but since both vue and vuetify don't have file input yet, and almost every single forum post out there only makes file input for images, I haven't been able to figure this one out yet, I'm submitting my form with jquery ajax.
my HTMl:

```
<template>
    <div class="uploader">
        <div class="upload-control">
            <label for="file">Select a file</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
            <div class="file-input">
                <input type="file" id="file" @change="onInputChange" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The script:

```
onInputChange(e) {
    this.form.music.push(e.target.files);
},
```

And finally the submit :

```
submit: function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        type:"POST",
        url:"{!! route('submit')!!}",
        data:{form:this.form},
        processData:true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
    }).done(response=>{
        this.notify("Submitted successfully!","success");
    })
},
```

Every time I try to submit console returns:

> TypeError: Illegal invocation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(BTW I've tried using npm modules but I just cant get it to work in Laravel, as I said, kind of a noob in javascript.)

Comment: You can't simple parse a file to a JSON structure, you'll need to take a look at [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), setting your contentType of your ajax request to `multipart/form-data`, parse the form and the file through separately. There's a tutorial on how to do that, [here](https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/) just substitute axios parts for jQuery ajax parts.

Comment: Thank you very much, will try it!